# AWS RDS updating SSL/TLS cert without restart

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I got a notification from AWS that I need to update my SSL/TLS cert for my RDS instances by 2/5/2020 ([As seen here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/amazon-rds-customers-update-your-ssl-tls-certificates-by-february-5-2020/)). I don't use SSL/TLS and I understand that I still have to do this, but I can do it without having to restart with the following command:

```
aws rds modify-db-instance --db-instance-identifier <myinstance> --ca-certificate-identifier rds-ca-2019 --no-certificate-rotation-restart --region us-east-1
```

After running this for one of my db instances, I got a json output with some details about the instance. Is there a way to verify that `--no-certificate-rotation-restart` was applied to the instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find out what SSL/TLS certificate is in use using the RDS console > Databases > Connectivity & security.

It will include something like:

> Certificate authority
>     rds-ca-2019  
>     Certificate authority date
>     Aug 22nd, 2024